# Why my $_POST is empty?

Tags: php, post, web

I have no time and too tired to struggle with this, so I decided to ask here: I've created the file **my.php** which contains only:

```
<?php var_dump( $_POST ); ?>
```

And then I open the file using browser like this:

```
www.domain.com/my.php?post1=hey&post2=ho&post3=letsgo
```

And in the browser I have *array(0) { }* as a response.

Question: What could I possibly done wrong??

Thanks!

Comment: These parameters are passed by GET method not POST so use $_GET

Comment: Try like this <?php var_dump( $_GET); ?>

Comment: [What is the difference between POST and GET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get)

Comment: _And in the browser I have array(0) { } as a response._ because its `get` not `post`

Comment: Thanks dudes! You're totally right! Please don't downvote poor noobie!

Comment: You could start by accepting an answer, people tend to look less at a question that is marked as resolved :)

Comment: @Blizz I can't dude ))) SO requires to wait 10 minutes before accepting an answer... 10 minutes is enough for noob to be punished and never ask stupid stuff again ... I guess this is the logic here ))

Comment: It's a fairly basic mistake, that is true. But then again: everyone had to start out at some point. In any case, I voted you up again, it's all I can do :)

Comment: @Blizz and I'm gladly accepting it, good sir! Have a delightful day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In URL are `GET` parameters, not `POST`.

```
echo $_GET['post1']; // hey
echo $_GET['post2']; // ho
echo $_GET['post3']; // letsgo
```

Comment: Cheers dude! Works! I should close this question before it gets -1000000

Answer (score 1):

You cant pass POST variables through URL.
u r using GET method..